# .hprof file prevents me from pushing to GitHub although it doesnt exist

Tags: git, github

When trying to push to GitHub a message appeared that a `.hprof` the file of 593.56mb was too big to push so I just deleted it since it wasn’t a useful file in the first place.

However, I am still getting the same message: `File android/java_pid82988.hprof is 593.56 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

When I check the `android` folder I don't see the .hprof file (because I deleted it) so I don't know why it's mentioning it! Please help.

[image]

Comment: It must still be in your history. I think that you committed it and delete it and committed the deletion. But the file is in the first commit and when git try to push it, GitHub is complaining. You have to rewrite your history to prevent the adding of the file.

Comment: @Philippe Hi! I was thinking something like this happened. Should I just brute force push?

Comment: You don't need because you history has not been pushed. Just rewrite it (without the file) and push normally.